# Error : The entry 'asp:System.Web.UI:System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' has already been added

Tags: asp.net, 32bit-64bit

We are working on a web application and the target deployment includes Windows 2003 64-bit. When we run the application on the 64-bit OS, it gives the following error:

```
The entry 'asp:System.Web.UI:System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' has already been added
```

The web.config file includes the following:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" theme="esl_theme">
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </controls>
</pages>
```

And if we remove the line `<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`, it seems to work.

Can somebody help to understand the problem and take corrective action? The application does not compile on 32-bit OS without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the root `web.config` from your application or from a subfolder?

Looks like your application inherits that reference from some parent `web.config`.

Could be from:

- Root web.config
- Machine's web.config

For your 64-bit problem, check if that assembly is compiled/built for 64-bit or not. Not worked much with 64-bit, but that must be the problem. Try referencing the 64-bit version.

Comment: It is the root web.config. Can you tell me what I need to see on machine.config?

Comment: You need to look for an entry of `asp:System.Web.UI:System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` assembly reference.

Comment: Thanks. I could actually locate a root web.config. Thanks for your help.